# Expand parent div based on child size + margin

Tags: css, border, margin

At the moment, I have div2 inside div1 and both have the same size.
I would like to add borders/margins to div2 but not reduce the size of div2 and instead expand size of div1.

Any idea how to do so?

[image]

Comment: No width/height on the outer div, but display:inline-block instead ... done.

Comment: Thank you! I will learn and study this inline-block option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer container do not need a `width` and `height` property. If this is the case the outer container (`.div1`) will expand if a child element (`.div2`) has `margin`. See the code example for better understanding :)

```css
.div1 {
  border: 4px solid #111;
  width: auto; /* remove width */
  height: auto; /* remove height */
  display: inline-block;  /* make it more flexible */
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
}

.div2.with-margin {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2 with-margin"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification!